# Python Tkinter key event locations lost in MacOS

Tags: macos, tkinter

I am porting a Python Tkinter application from Linux to Mac OS X Mavericks.

In part of the application, I have a Canvas up and the user uses key presses to do things - for example, pressing 'z' causes the view to zoom in on the cursor.  This means that I need to know where the mouse was when the key is pressed.  Under Linux this was no problem, because `event.x` and `event.y` correctly give the window coordinates where the key was pressed, for example:

`skdisp.bind('p',(lambda event : skdisp.pan(event)))`

where `skdisp.pan(event)` is (obviously) a method that pans the display.

This works fine under Linux, but under MacOS the key events do not hand back the cursor coordinates correctly -- `event.x` and `event.y` have small, constant negative values.

Here's a small example that reproduces this problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Put up a tiny gui and report window coordinates at which
user types a letter."""

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
prompt = ' Press any letter '
label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt), bg='white')
label1.pack()

def key(event):
   msg = "event xy %d %d" % (event.x, event.y)
   label1.config(text=msg)  

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.mainloop()
```

On a linux system, as you type letters into the window, the mouse coordinates are echoed in the display, but the Mac does not do this.

Thanks - my very first Stack post, so please be gentle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in OSX. To be honest I was initially a bit surprised that it works on linux since the cursor is completely uninvolved in the event. In all my years of programming with tk and tkinter I've never thought to grab the x/y coordinate of a key press. It's a documented feature, though, so it *should* work.

Regardless, you can work around this by using the various `winfo_*` methods to get the x,y coordinate of the pointer and the x,y coordinate of the window, and doing a little math. For example:

```
def key(event):
    px,py = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
    rx,ry = (event.widget.winfo_rootx(), event.widget.winfo_rooty())
    cx,cy = (px-rx, py-ry)
    msg = "event xy %d %d" % (cx, cy)
    label1.config(text=msg)
```

Comment: Bryan -Your workaround works perfectly.  You saved me a great deal of trouble -- thank you VERY much!